# subsetting using column names as objects

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to subset a data frame using a column names stored in an object.  Is this possible? Here is an example:

```
ReallyLongColNameA <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)

ReallyLongColNameB <- c(6,5,4,3,2,1)

ReallyLongColNameC <- c(7,8,9,10,11,12)

X <- data.frame(ReallyLongColNameA, ReallyLongColNameB, ReallyLongColNameC)
```

can i store a column name as such:

```
ShortColNameB <- names(X[2])
```

and then subset using the column name stored in object `ShortColNameB`

I can subset the following:

```
subX <- X[X$ReallyLongColB == 6,]
```

To get:

```
ReallyLongColA  ReallyLongColB  ReallyLongColC
1               6               7
```

But what if I wanted the following desired output by using the column name stored in an object (`ShortColNameB`)?:

```
ReallyLongColA  ReallyLongColB
1               6
```

Comment: Use `[` for subsetting i.e. `X[ShortColNameB]`

Comment: Sorry making edits to my original question.

Comment: You said you get an error from your code. What does the error say?

Comment: You can do `X[X[[ShortColNameB]]==6,]`

Comment: Thanks akrun, will try and get back....
While, this works, how do I remove colC from the output at the same time?

Comment: OK, so I can subset with the following:

    `subset(X, X[[ShortColNameB]]==6, select=c(ReallyLongColNameA,        ReallyLongColNameB))`

but, how do i use the object ShortColNameB, instead of "ReallyLongColNameB"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily remove the last column by subsetting on column numbers.

`X[X[[ShortColNameB]]==6,c(1,2)]`

You define what rows you want by filtering on the `==6` for `ShortColNameB`, and you define the columns you want by selecting the numbers (e.g. 1st and 2nd column, A & B).

Comment: YES!  Thanks! 
I just got the same result by : 
    `X[X["ReallyLongColNameA"]==6, c("ReallyLongColNameA", ShortColNameB)]`